# Не записывается значение в ячейку GridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress

```cs
if(ForKafs.CheckKafsOp1() != null)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < mRecievedChecked.Length; i++)
    {
        gridViewKafs.SetRowCellValue(mRecievedChecked[i], gridColumn3, "Выявлены ошибки");
    }
}
```

Данный код, в случае его выполнения, должен прописывать в определённую ячейку текст "Выявлены ошибки". При пошаговом выполнении вижу, что программа заходит в это место и выполняет строку, которая должна записывать значение, но ячейка в GridView остаётся пустой. Редактирование gridColumn3 разрешено.

В чём может быть ошибка?

Comment: ты ведь не видишь визуально? попробуй пройтись через debug, посмотри, в gridViewKafs в строках есть ли это значение? если есть, то нужно обновить grid.

Comment: попробуйте после занесения строки => вывести ее в коде. Возможно строка записывается, но ен отрабатывает отображение

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц проверяю таким образом: string temp = gridViewKafs.GetRowCellValue(mRecievedChecked[i], gridColumn3).ToString(); выскакивает NullRefererenceException

Comment: А row создан, когда вы ячейкам значение присваиваете? Попробуйте сперва `gridViewKafs.AddNewRow();`, а затем `SetRowCellValue`

Comment: @АртёмОконечников не сработало

Comment: приведенный код абсолютно корректен, но предполагает что:   
1) mRecievedChecked[i] соответствует валидному дескриптору строки, то есть такая строка в гриде есть ([Indentifying Rows](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114736/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/getting-started/walkthroughs/grid-view-columns-rows-and-cells/tutorial-identifying-rows)).   
2) Колонка gridColumn3 через [FieldName](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn.FieldName) привязана к свойству типа String.

Comment: "Редактирование gridColumn3 разрешено" - подразумевается что пользователь тоже может ввести значение, и оно остается после перевода фокуса не исчезает)?

Comment: @Uranus да, это и подразумевается, но понял, что это не то